# Slack post by bot not always containing

Tags: slack-api

I'm using the "[incoming webhooks](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks)" feature of Slack to post notifications to a channel. I'm also using the "icon_emoji" feature to decorate the messages and to highlight the different types of messages. However I find that the image doesn't show up consistently:

[image]

Ie. only when it says `BOT` does the image also show up.

Any ideas what the issue is? Ideally I would like for the image to show up each message so that they can be scanned easily (some messages are more informative and others need to be acted upon in a timely manner).

Comment: What do you mean by "Does not show up consistently"?

Comment: @WilhelmKlopp - see the screenshot included in the question. Those are two very similar messages (sent by the same code) but the image only shows up for the first one (I would expect it to show for both of them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Slack is automatically consolidating consecutive messages that are sent within a certain time frame. So the bot icon will show for the first message only and consecutive messages will display beneath the first without the bot icon.

This is standard behavior of Slack and works the same for user messages. Don't believe there is any way to turn that off.

Comment: Thank you. I'll be including the icon in the messages as a workaround.

Comment: While testing the simplest thing to do is keep on posting manually to the channel in between the bot postings - this means the icon is always shown for each "new" message

Comment: yeah that works. it works for testing (I do the same), but I guess its not a solution for production bot, unless you are ok with lots of extra random messages in your channel

Comment: Man you saved me from an hour of debugging. Thanks! Posting manually from Slack indeed forces the icon to be displayed.