# Is it possible to set icon_emoji with the new incoming webhooks?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I've been going around in circles and I think icon_emoji is now part of legacy code, but I keep seeing examples of people using icon_emoji floating around.

I have a custom slack app set up, which uses the new blocks etc. I would love to use the icon_emoji but haven't had any luck figuring it out. I've tried using curl as well, and was also unsuccessful there too. The slack docs mention it doesn't work with bot users, but I haven't set one up?

I'm just an emoji girl living in an emoji world, would love to figure this out if possible!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

It's working for me using curl to send to `https://hooks.slack.com/services/...`. more information at https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks

example:

```
curl -X POST --data-urlencode "payload={\"channel\": \"#test\", \"username\": \"myBot\", \"text\": \"hello\", \"icon_emoji\": \":ghost:\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/...
```

Also the icon may only show up once due to message consolidation. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42109435/2045153

Answer (score 0):

I executed the exact curl request that @AlphaCactus shared and I'm still yet to see the custom fields--`username` and `icon_emoji`-- being set on Slack side. I'm still seeing the default values that are set in App configuration.

Reading the documentation https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks, I noticed the following information block:

> You cannot override the default channel (chosen by the user who
> installed your app), username, or icon when you're using Incoming
> Webhooks to post messages. Instead, these values will always inherit
> from the associated Slack app configuration.

Therefore, I believe one needs to use [chat.postMessage](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) to set these custom fields.

Because I know by experience, that `chat.PostMessage` sets these custom fields.

Comment: you need to add scope `chat:write.customize` in addition to `chat.postMessage` to change thouse fields

Comment: can you share an example? The docs seems pretty explicit about this not being possible with incoming webhooks.

Comment: @mnach: I tried adding `chat:write.customize` (which also added `chate:write`). There is no `chat.postMessage`.  Most importantly, it did not work.  I believe the documentation is explicit and correct. Icon can't be overridden using webhooks. Also seems markdown is not processed, at least with a simple text message.